# Showing and hiding element, making my code more useful

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning about JavaScript and events. I am interested in learning the JavaScript and not jQuery until I am better at JavaScript.

I wrote this code that will show and hide my div because I basically want to be able to use this code in future web development projects but at the moment it will only apply to one element on page but what if I want to have a few pop up boxes. I understand I will have to have the element positioned absolute.

Can I also ask anyone that is good at JavaScript events to check my code to see if it is well written or if it could be improved? I am just a learning.

To make my questions clearer:

1. How would I make this code more usable for more than one element?
2. Is my code well written or does it look like a noob wrote it?

```
<style>
    a#button{
        background-color: #FFFF00;
        display:block;
    }

    div#menu{
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<body>
<a id="button" href="#">Click Me</a>
<div id="menu">SUPRISE</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("click", whereWasClicked, false); // listener for any clicks on the document.

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", displaySuprise, false);


var clicked;
function whereWasClicked(){
    clicked = event.target;
    //check to see if user clicks outside of the
    if (tog = 1 && clicked != menu) {
            menu.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click Me";
            tog = 0;
        }
}
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var tog = 0; // set up a toggle so you can display block and then none.
function displaySuprise(){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(tog == 0){
        menu.style.display = "block";
        this.innerHTML = "Opened!";
        tog = 1;
    } else {
        menu.style.display = "none";
        this.innerHTML = "Click Me";
        tog = 0;
    }
    // check to see if the user has clicked anywhere off the new element.

}
</script>
```

Comment: My initial thought is -- you are really doing great. Doesn't look like NOOBs code. Think of using `prototype` to improve modularity of the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uPwNy/14/

Comment: @Raynos when the user clicks away from the element the element should disappear.

Comment: @jamcoupe I know, that's bad design. I fixed it for you. Now when you click the button again it hides itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Item 1:** I'd suggest getting rid of all global variables except `tog`.  They don't look like they are needed and just open you up for a potential conflict with other global variables.

**Item 2:** This line of code:

```
if (tog = 1 && clicked != menu) {
```

should probably be:

```
if (tog == 1 && clicked != menu) {
```

Comparisons are done with `==` or `===`, not with `=` which is an assignment.

**Item 3:**  `addEventListener()` does not exist in versions of IE before IE9, so you will need to use `attachEvent()` if `addEventListener()` is not present.

**Item 4:** Here's a version I've done that gets rid of all globals except `tog` (which I renamed `menuVisble` and made it a boolean.  It also uses anonymous functions (less global namespace pollution) for the handlers and makes some other cleanups.  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MEaPs/.

```
var menuVisible = false; // set up a toggle so you can display block and then none.

// listener for any clicks on the document.
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var clicked = e.target;
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    //check to see if user clicks outside of the
    if (menuVisible && clicked != menu) {
            menu.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click Me";
            menuVisible = false;
        }

}, false); 

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (menuVisible){
        menu.style.display = "none";
        this.innerHTML = "Click Me";
        menuVisible = false;
    } else {
        menu.style.display = "block";
        this.innerHTML = "Opened!";
        menuVisible = true;
    }
}, false);
```

**Item 5:**  And here's a version with no globals at all.  It uses the class of the menu to control and discern visibility.  You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/96NfD/.

```
// listener for any clicks on the document.
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var menuVisible = menu.className.indexOf("hidden") == -1;
    //check to see if user clicks outside of the
    if (menuVisible && e.target != menu) {
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click Me";
            menu.className = "hidden";
        }

}, false); 

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var menuVisible = menu.className.indexOf("hidden") == -1;
    if (menuVisible) {
        this.innerHTML = "Click Me";
        menu.className = "hidden";
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = "Opened!";
        menu.className = "";
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I know about the pre IE9 problem but I am not going to concern myself over it until I need to (when I am making proper websites.)

Comment: It seems that I have to have `tog` as a global variable for it to toggle properly

Comment: @jamcoupe - Yes, that's why I said to "get rid of all global variables except `tog`".  You wouldn't technically need tog either if you just examine the object to see if it's visible or not, but that would require writing a little more code.

Comment: @jamcoupe - I added two new versions of the code for you to look at.

Comment: your code looks much better and I haven't looked into `.className` yet. but I understand how your code is working! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

jfriend00's answer is great.

And I think you can rewrite your click-outside function like this for llater reuse.

```
var clickOutside = function(element, action) {
  return function(e) {
    action(e.target !== element);
  };
};

document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  clickOutside(menu, function(isOutside) {
    if(isOutside && menuVisible) {
      // hide your menu
    }
  }),
  false
);
```